# TabController disappears when using swipe gesture

Tags: ios, swipe-gesture, uitabcontroller

I have an app with a 3 tabs. I want to swipe right or left to go to another tab.

My code:

```
//Swipe Between Tabs
    let rightSwipe = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("handleSwipes:"))
    let leftSwipe = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("handleSwipes:"))
    rightSwipe.direction = .Right
    leftSwipe.direction = .Left
    view.addGestureRecognizer(rightSwipe)
    view.addGestureRecognizer(leftSwipe)
    //end Swipe
```

and the function to carry it out is

```
func handleSwipes(sender:UISwipeGestureRecognizer) {
    if (sender.direction == .Left) {
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("PantryList")
        let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: vc)

        self.presentViewController(navigationController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    if (sender.direction == .Right) {
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ToDoList")
        let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: vc)

        self.presentViewController(navigationController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

My problem is that tabBarController at the bottom disappears when swipe is used. From what I have found it has to do with the "presentViewController" method. Is this what is causing it and is there a way to do it without losing the tabBarController? I really don't want to use prepareForSegueWithIdentifier if I don't have to. That seems like more work than needs to be done unless that's how it has to be done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (sender.direction == .Right) {
    self.navigationController.tabBarController.selectedIndex = 1
}
```

Comment: awesome, works how I wanted. Except one thing...I did enjoy the transition of the screen sliding up from the bottom when it transitioned. I have no idea how to do the transitions and lucked out on the last one haha. How can I get this back with the 'selectedIndex:' method?

Answer (score 1):

Of course it's because you are presenting view controller on top of current view controller. To switch between `UITabbarController` `viewControllers`, you can use `setSelectedIndex:` method, in your case, your first vc will have 0 index, second and third 1 and 2 respectively. Just switch the selected index on swipe, and you are done! Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I too think your problem is with the presentViewController:. Assuming the swipe handling code is in the UITabBarController, what you are doing here is pushing a VC on top of the whole tabcontroller.

I'll try to move the [selected view controller's view](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITabBarController_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITabBarController/selectedViewController) along the next VC view to be displayed (in the direction given by the swipe move), then change the value of the UITabBarController selectedViewController to your new VC.